# Is it possible to implement operator overloading for apply::Apply?

Tags: rust, functional-programming, operator-overloading

Is there any way to implement [operator overloading](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/ops.html) for [`apply::Apply`](https://docs.rs/apply/0.3.0/apply/trait.Apply.html)?

> In Rust, many of the operators can be overloaded via traits. That is, some operators can be used to accomplish different tasks based on their input arguments. This is possible because operators are syntactic sugar for method calls. For example, the + operator in a + b calls the add method (as in a.add(b)). This add method is part of the Add trait. Hence, the + operator can be used by any implementor of the Add trait.

```
/// Represents a type which can have functions applied to it (implemented
/// by default for all types).
pub trait Apply<Res> {
    /// Apply a function which takes the parameter by value.
    fn apply<F: FnOnce(Self) -> Res>(self, f: F) -> Res
    where Self: Sized {
        f(self)
    }
}

impl<T: ?Sized, Res> Apply<Res> for T {
    // use default definitions...
}
```

[Crate overload](https://docs.rs/overload/latest/overload/)

For instance,

```rust
let string = 1 >> (|x| x * 2) >> (|x: i32| x.to_string());
```

for

```rust
let string = 1.apply(|x| x * 2).apply(|x: i32| x.to_string());
```

Comment: What do you mean by "implement operator overloading"? You can always implement the traits in `std::ops`.

Comment: I think I made my question clear, and the term is from the official document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. Operators don't go on traits, they go on types. It does not make sense to ask "what is the implementation of `>>` for `Apply`" but it does make sense to ask "what is the implementation of `>>` for `u8`." So what you could try to do is to define `Apply` as you've defined it, and now:

```rust
impl<T, Res, F> std::ops::Shr<F> for T
where
    T: Apply<Res>,
    F: FnOnce(T) -> Res
{
    type Output = Res;
    fn shr(self, rhs: F) -> Res {
        rhs(self)
    }
}
```

This *almost* works, except that the compiler reports an error, citing

> only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter

The reason for this error is that you have no guarantee that another crate has not implemented the same trait for the same type. If another crate defined a

```rust
impl<F: FnOnce(MyType) -> String> std::ops::Shr<F> for MyType { ... }
```

its not clear what should happen, since now the `>>` operator has been defined twice for the same type. You could write such an `impl` if you replaced `MyType` with some specific type that is local to your crate, but of course now the `>>` thing won't work for all other types.

Comment: Well thanks, and I know operators are on types, however, the official document says "In Rust, many of the operators can be overloaded via traits." that I have to quote now in my Question, and if you are not satisfied with the expression there, please claim to them.

Comment: @KenSmooth it says "can be overloaded via traits" meaning that they can be overloaded *using* traits, not that they can be overloaded *on* traits

Comment: I think such a context is pretty clear in my Question, and I do not agree to  "It does not make sense to ask  "what is the implementation of >> for Apply" with your rephrase.

Comment: @KenSmooth what the documentation means is that you can use eg `std::ops::Shr` to overload `>>`, `std::ops::Add` to overload `+`, `std::ops::Deref` to overload `*`, etc. You can use *particular* traits to overload operators *on types*

Comment: Is this not possible even using Macro? Operator overlong on `<T>T`

Comment: It is possible to write a macro that turns all invocations of `>>` inside the macro into some call to a particular method, but I strongly recommend against this, it is bound to be confusing.

Comment: Ok, Thanks again.